# How to make the Geoserver SLD with vector layer(linestring geometry) if rasterize gray color lines to RGB color line using RasterSymbolizer Colormap?

Tags: geoserver, colormap, wms, rasterize, sld

I am a starter with the Geoserver.

I created lineString vector layer with lineSymbolizer SLD style.
And the vector layer is connected by postgis and that layer only have linestring geometry rowdata. other attributes values does not exist(only linstring coordinates)

grayscaled layer
[image: grayscaled layer]

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
     xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
     xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <!-- a Named Layer is the basic building block of an SLD document -->
      <NamedLayer>
        <Name>line</Name>
        <UserStyle>
          <Title>Line</Title>
          <Abstract>greyscaled line</Abstract>
          <FeatureTypeStyle>
            <Rule>
              <Name>rule1</Name>
              <Title>greyscaled Line</Title>
              <Abstract></Abstract>
              <LineSymbolizer>
                <Stroke>
                  <CssParameter name="stroke">#000</CssParameter>
                   <CssParameter name="opacity">0.1</CssParameter>
                </Stroke>
              </LineSymbolizer>
            </Rule>
          </FeatureTypeStyle>
        </UserStyle>
      </NamedLayer>
    </StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

and I want to convert or set this layer greyscaled color to RGB coloring by quantity.
the outputs should be like this image

RGB Colormap
[image: RGB Colormap]

[Geoserver RasterSymbolizer](https://docs.geoserver.org/master/en/user/styling/sld/reference/rastersymbolizer.html#sld-reference-rastersymbolizer)

I tried make new SLD using 'RasterSymbolizer Colormap' from geoserver, but I failed..

Is it possible use rasterSymbolizer in linestring vector layer map?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: what quantity do you want to color by? You said there were no attributes